# PyCharm does not recognize dictionary value type

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pycharm, type-hinting

I have a simple code snippet where I set dictionary values as empty lists:

```
new_dict = {}
for i in range(1, 13):
    new_dict[i] = []
```

Now, if inside the loop on the next line I would type `new_dict[i]` and add a dot, I expect PyCharm to show me a list of methods available for a `list`, but PyCharm fails to recognize the dictionary value type in this simple case:

[image]

Why is it happening and what can I do? Using PyCharm 2016.1.2, Python 2.7.10.

---

As a workaround, I can explicitly add a [type hint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html), letting PyCharm know that `new_dict` is a dictionary where keys are integers and values are lists by adding a `# type: dict[int, list]` inline comment:

[image]

Comment: remember that type hinting is made without running any code.  I can't think of many cases where it would reliably be able to guess what kind of data is stored in the dictionary.

Comment: If automatic type hinting was implemented for cases where it could be certain what the type was, then I'd imagine lots of people would complain that it was buggy / rarely works correctly.  The example you have posted or an equivalent with any python literal or maybe a function call that the return value is annotated are about the only times I'd see it working well.

Comment: Since the 'value' of the key, value pairs can pretty much be anything, I think it's a lot to ask of PyCharm to automagically guess the type of the value object. As @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen said, PyCharm isn't actually running your Python code, so it can't know the type. Seems like the type hint is a good option here.

Comment: You are right. I am afraid this is too much I'm asking. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I think you should consider summarizing your thoughts in an answer. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like a reasonable expectation for `new_dict[i] = []` on the line directly above to be a sufficient type hint, but I suppose "static typing"-style hints are easier to parse.

Comment: I'm actually already quite impressed that the type hint works

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 talked to one of the PyCharm devs who specializes on type hinting and static typing. He said they are working on it and we should expect that to work in future PyCharm releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider a slightly more complex scenario with a variable:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i%2:
        x = 3
    else:
        x = "hello"
    x. #type hint for both int and str
```

In this case the last line will give us all the methods of `int`s and `str`s because PyCharm is able to detect that `x` will either be an `int` or a `str`

Now replace all the occurences of `x` with `my_dict[i]`:

```
my_dict = {}
for i in range(10):
    if i%2:
        my_dict[i] = 3
    else:
        my_dict[i] = "hello"
    my_dict[i]. #no type hint :(
```

All of the same rules apply as above, we know (and PyCharm would be able to figure out) that `my_dict[i]` is either going to be an `int` or a `str`.

However what would you expect to happen if you were not initializing the `dict`?

```
def f(my_dict): #or even (my_dict:dict)
    my_dict[1]. #cannot possibly expect a type hint
```

In this case there is no way to know what the values of the dict are other then adding an explicit annotation just like you would in your example case:

```
def f(my_dict:"dict[int,list]"):
    my_dict[1]. #get all the list methods
```

This really reinforces some lines from [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Readability counts.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

(I include readability because the explicit type hint is a lot easier to read then a potentially buried assignment)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are expecting PyCharm to be able to infer too much from the code.

Providing the type hint annotation gives PyCharm the information it needs to show the code completion options.  In this case you are explicitly telling PyCharm what type the value of each dictionary element is going to be.

Without the type hint annotation you are expecting PyCharm to be able to know what the dictionary's element value is going to be when you are assigning it inside of a loop.  That is way too much assumption for PyCharm to make.  As Tadhg McDonald-Jensen mentioned in the comments, this is just too dynamic of a situation for PyCharm to figure it out reliably.  The code completion would be wrong too often.