# How to add python docstring for dict of dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, docstring

I have an object that is a dict of dicts. I would like to tell my editor this object is so, how can I do this? Currently I have:

```
def do_somthing(dict_of_dicts):
    """
    :type dict_of_dicts: dict of dict
    """

    for key, value in dict_of_dicts.items():
            for key2, value2 in value.items():
                print('Key')
```

However, my editor (Pycharm) does not seem to be registering this.

Comment: can you provide the entire code here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm does not recognize dictionary value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010854/pycharm-does-not-recognize-dictionary-value-type)

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using type hinting using [`Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict):

```
from typing import Dict, Any

def do_somthing(dict_of_dicts: Dict[Any, Dict]):
    """
    :type dict_of_dicts: Dict[Any, Dict]
    """

    for key, value in dict_of_dicts.items():
            for key2, value2 in value.items():
                print('Key')
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! (Just a note, I had to change Dict to dict to work

Comment: Well `Dict` is the type notation, `dict` would be the method to cast to dictionary. Have you included the import from typing?

Comment: @superdee You shouldn't have to do that, and it probably doesn't mean what you want it to mean. When you use `Dict`, what happens?

Comment: My IDE doesn't autofill things such as .items() for value

Comment: That's odd, even if you try `Dict[Any, Dict[Any, Any]]`? Just to understand how your  IDE reads type hinting.

Comment: Still no luck, but at least I got it working. However I now have one more question, let's say at the top of my class file I want to define a dictionary of lists (python3):

    branch_urls: dict[str, dict] = {}

This produces an error TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You would go with `Dict[Any, List]`, importing [`List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) from typing.

Comment: Well of course, type hinting is just that, type hinting. You cannot use it in variable assignment.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use PyCharm, but… it understands type annotations, right? So, specify it as an annotation:

```
from typing import Dict, Any

def do_something(dict_of_dicts: Dict[Any, Dict[Any, Any]]):
    # ...
```

Or you can even define a generic `DictOfDict` type (generic on the outer key, inner key, and inner value):

```
from typing import Dict, Any, TypeVar, Generic:

K1, K2, V = TypeVar('K1'), TypeVar('K2'), TypeVar('V')
class DictOfDicts(Dict[K1, Dict[K2, V]]): ...

def do_something(dict_of_dicts: DictOfDicts[Any, Any, Any]):
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might already find your answer, but to others who stumble upon this thread:

Try this, no need to import `typing`:

```
dict[dict]
```

it will be displayed in docstring as:

```
 Dict[dict]
```

In the case of your example:

```
def do_somthing(dict_of_dicts):
    """
    :type dict_of_dicts: dict[Any, dict]
    """

    for key, value in dict_of_dicts.items():
            for key2, value2 in value.items():
                print('Key')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also add `param`:

```
def do_somthing(dict_of_dicts):
    """
    :param dict_of_dicts: A dictionary of dictionaries.
    :type dict_of_dicts: dict of dict
    """

for key, value in dict_of_dicts.items():
        for key2, value2 in value.items():
            print('Key')
```

I suggest reading this article: https://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html